# Add custom table style for tinyMCE

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tinymce

I wish to add custom table style for TinyMCE how can I specify how I want my table/header/rows styled?

```
    <table class="tdata " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
width="600" style="margin-top: 8px; font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif; 
width: 600px; color: #000000;">




<th style="margin: 0px; padding: 2px 0px; border-top-width: 2px; 
border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: black;
border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; 
border-bottom-color: #aaaaaa; vertical-align: bottom; 
font-size: 10px; width:144px; text-align:center;">Company</th>


     formats : {

     customformat : {inline : 'span', styles : {verticalAlign: 'middle',
 borderWidth: '0px 0px 1px', borderStyle:'none none solid', 
borderbottomcolor: '#aaaaaa', fontFamily: 'tahoma, arial,
 sans-serif', fontSize: '10px', color: '333333'}, attributes : 
{title : 'My custom format'}}
            },
```

Comment: +1 good question, that can be easiliy answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add your own css file to the editor iframe head which will then get apllied to the editor content. To include this css file you simple need to use the tinymce configuration parameter [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css)

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        content_css : "http::/your_server/your_css/your_custom_content.css"    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to

\config\tinyMceConfig.config

```
<config>

<config key="extended_valid_elements">table[class=tdata]</config>

</config>
```

And so on